Will an overstay and ban in Australia affect travel to Singapore?
I overstayed in Australia last 2021. The immigration officer told me I'm banned for 3 years. My 3-year ban ended last April. Will this affect my travel to Singapore for holidays?
I'm planning to stay there for 3 days. Will the immigration officer stop me? Will they know my history?

Do you need a visa to enter Singapore? What is your citizenship?

Note: it is confidential which information country shares (and at what level). We do not know about it. And if they ask you, you should tell the truth (if they know, they may just want to know the reason). Also short overstay is much different to a long overstay

@NicolasFormichella . Im from philippines, singapore is visa free. all they need is ticket roundtrip and accomodation while staying in singapore

@GiacomoCatenazzi I already serve my 3 years penalty from Australian Immigration. Do I need to worry about when I have plan to travel singapore for 3 days? and singapore is visa free. all I need is roundtrip ticket and had accomodation

@HaniMalabote Is the overstay obvious from eg visa and entry/exit stamps in your passport?

I have renewal passport already,doesnt show anything from my previous country I overstayed.

@Traveller Australia has not used physical visas or stamped passports since 2012.

The truth is that we do not know, here are a lot of factors that go into the equation :
As @Giacomo Catenazzi states:

Note: it is confidential which information country shares (and at what level). We do not know about it. And if they ask you, you should tell the truth (if they know, they may just want to know the reason). Also short overstay is much different to a long overstay.

As you are visa-free for Singapore, you will probably have less questioning on entry, but we can't know before you are in front of the officer.
The end point is : be honest if that ever comes up. Lying or anything will be much worse (you do not want to be sent to prison or even caned for lying) than if you are honest.

Note that you are likely to be allowed to use the Automated Clearance on departure (and on further visits with the same passport) if the officer deems you to be low-risk enough.
